# Browser Cookie never expires

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, fastapi, uvicorn, cookie-httponly

I'm implementing for first time a **login Auth with HTTpOnly Cookie**. In my case, the cookie it's created when user calls login method in a **Python service** with fastapi and uvicorn.

I've read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) documentation to implement the expires property and so, the browser delete this cookie when the time expires.

I've implemented the Cookie in Python with http.cookies and [Morsel](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.cookies.html#morsel-objects) to apply the **HttpOnly** property like this:

```
from http import cookies
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Cookie, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

mytoken = 'blablabla'

def getUtcDate():
    sessionDate = datetime.now()
    sessionDate += timedelta(minutes=2)
    return sessionDate.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

@app.get('cookietest')
def getCookie(response: Response):
   cookie = cookies.Morsel()
   cookie['httponly'] = True
   cookie['version'] = '1.0.0'
   cookie['domain'] = '127.0.0.1'
   cookie['path'] = '/'
   cookie['expires'] = getUtcDate()
   cookie['max-age'] = 120
   cookie['samesite'] = 'Strict'
   cookie.set("jwt", "jwt", mytoken)

   response.headers.append("Set-Cookie", cookie.output())

   return {'status':'ok'}
```

Doing this, the Cookies looks correctly in the browser when I call the 'cookietest' endpoint, the evidence:

[image: Cookie with expiration date]

As you can see in the picture, the cookie has an expiration datetime in Expires / Max-Age:"Wed, 12 Oct 2022 11:24:58 GMT", 2 minutes after logging in (if the user logging at 14:05:00, the cookies expires at 14:07:00)

My problem is that **any browser doesn't delete the cookie when the expire time has been exceeded**, so this it's confusing me. If I let several minutes pass and then make a request to another endpoint (like http://127.0.0.1:8000/info), the cookie still exists in http headers.

What is the problem? What i'm doing wrong? I'm reading a lot of documentation about cookie storing and expiration and I can't see anything about this issue.

Many thanks Regards

### EDITED : PROBLEM SOLVED

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17865804/chris) says, using the set_cookie method from FastApi the problem was solved.

I still wonder why the MSD documentation indicates that the date format must be a specific one which does not cause the browser to delete the Cookie, but indicating the time in seconds works correctly.

```
@app.get("/cookietest")
async def cookietest(response: Response):
    response.set_cookie(
        key='jwt', 
        value=getToken(), 
        max_age=120, 
        expires=120, 
        path='/', 
        secure=False, 
        httponly=True, 
        samesite="strict", 
        domain='127.0.0.1'
    )
    return {"Result": "Ok"}
```

Comment: Just to let you know that you could create cookies using the `set_cookie` method of the `Response` object, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804). See the relevant [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/) and [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie) as well.

Comment: You can set the `expires` flag in the `set_cookie` method, which takes an integer that defines the number of seconds until the cookie expires. For instance, if you want the cookie to expire in 2 minutes from the time it is created, use `expires=120`.

Comment: Ok, I change my code using set_cookie method from fastapi and now works but, why the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) documentation says that Expires use a DateTime with format like this "Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT"??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the `expires` flag, the date must be exactly in the format you are currently using, as well as in the `GMT` (Greenwich Mean Time) timezone. The reason that your cookie does not get expired 2 minutes after it has been created is because you are using [datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), which returns the current **local** date and time.

Thus, for instance, if your current local timezone is `GMT+2` and time is `20:30:00` (hence, `GMT` time is `18:30:00`), creating a cookie that expires at `20:32:00 GMT` will actually tell the browser to delete this cookie in 2 hours and 2 minutes (from the time it has been created). If you look at the cookie's `Expires / Max-Age` column in your browser's DevTools (e.g., on Chrome, go to `Network` tab in the DevTools, click on the request's name and then on the `Cookies` tab), you will notice a `Z` at the end of the datetime, which means `UTC` (Coordinated Universal Time)—that is, an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. You can check the response headers as well, where you can see the cookie's `expires` flag set to `20:32:00 GMT`. There is no noticable [time difference between `UTC` and `GMT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/what-is-the-difference-between-utc-and-gmt) (if you would like to learn more about their differences, have a look at this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-GMT-and-UTC/answers/15830760)).

Hence, you could either replace `.now()` with [`.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) in your code:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def get_expiry():
    expiry = datetime.utcnow()
    expiry += timedelta(seconds=120)
    return expiry.strftime('%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT')
```

or use [time.gmtime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime), passing as `secs` argument the [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) (which returns the time in seconds) plus the desired lease time (in seconds):

```py
import time

def get_expiry():
    lease = 120  # seconds
    end = time.gmtime(time.time() + lease)
    return time.strftime('%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT', end)
```

For either the above two methods, use:

```
cookie['expires'] = get_expiry()
```

You can also use the undocumented way of passing the expiry time directly in seconds instead. For instance:

```
cookie['expires'] = 120
```

An alternative to `expires` is the `max-age` flag , which specifies the cookie's expiration in seconds from the current moment (similar to the above way). If set to zero or a negative value, the cookie is deleted immediately. Example:

```
cookie['max-age'] = 120
```

#### Note:

If both `expires` and `max-age` are set, `max-age` has precedence (see relevant [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes)).

Also, as per [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.1):

> 4.1.2.1.  The `Expires` Attribute
>
> The `Expires` attribute indicates the maximum lifetime of the cookie,
> represented as the **date and time** at which the cookie expires. The user
> agent is not required to retain the cookie until the specified date
> has passed. In fact, user agents often evict cookies due to memory
> pressure or privacy concerns.
>
> 4.1.2.2.  The `Max-Age` Attribute
>
> The `Max-Age` attribute indicates the maximum lifetime of the cookie,
> represented as the number of **seconds** until the cookie expires. The
> user agent is not required to retain the cookie for the specified
> duration. In fact, user agents often evict cookies due to memory
> pressure or privacy concerns.
>
> ```
> NOTE: Some existing user agents do not support the Max-Age 
> attribute. User agents that do not support the Max-Age attribute 
> ignore the attribute.
> ```
>
> If a cookie has **both** the `Max-Age` and the `Expires` attribute, the
> `Max-Age` attribute has precedence and controls the expiration date of
> the cookie. If a cookie has **neither** the `Max-Age` nor the `Expires`
> attribute, the user agent will retain the cookie until "the current
> session is over" (as defined by the user agent).

Also note, as mentioned in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) regarding the `expires` flag:

> **Warning**: Many web browsers have a *session restore* feature that will save all tabs and restore them the next time the browser is used.
> Session cookies will also be restored, as if the browser was never
> closed.

Another thing to note is that, since Sep 2022, [Chrome limits the cookie's `max-age` to 400 days](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4887741241229312):

> When cookies are set with an explicit `Expires/Max-Age` attribute the
> **value will now be capped to no more than 400 days** in the future.
> Previously, there was no limit and cookies could expire as much as
> multiple millennia in the future.

### Using FastAPI/Starlette

It should also be noted that FastAPI/Starlette provides an easier way to set cookies on the `Response` object, using the [`set_cookie`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/responses.py#L103) method, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093). As per [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie):

> - `max_age` - An **integer** that defines the lifetime of the cookie in    **seconds**. A negative integer or a value of `0` will discard
>   the cookie immediately. `Optional`
> - `expires` - An **integer** that defines the number of **seconds**    until the cookie expires. `Optional`

Example from [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
def create_cookie(response: Response):
    response.set_cookie(key='token', value='token-value', max_age=120, expires=120, httponly=True)
    return {'message': 'success'}
```

Comment: A lot of information and so usefull. Thanks for your explanation and time.